# Kotlin - Void vs. Unit vs. Nothing

Tags: kotlin, generics, types, functional-programming

Kotlin has three types that are very similar in nature:

- `Void`
- `Unit`
- `Nothing`

It almost seems like they're making the JavaScript mistake:

- `null`
- `undefined`
- `void(0)`

Assuming that they *haven't* fallen into the same mistake, what are they all for, and how do they differ?

Comment: @mobibob I believe the rationale in Kotlin is that all functions _return_ an object, even if that object is `Unit`. In contrast, IIRC, `void` in Java isn't an object of any type, rather than absence of one. Also `Unit` has been around since Kotlin 1.0, whereas `UInt` was introduced in Kotlin 1.3. You're always going to find very similar words in all languages (for example, "there", "their" and "they're" in English, and people still confuse those frequently).

Answer (score 186, accepted):

The `Void` type is from Java. You generally won't use this from Kotlin unless you're using some Java-library that uses it.

The `Unit` type is what you return from a function that doesn't return anything of interest. Such a function is usually performing some kind of side effect. The unit type has only one possible value, which is [the `Unit` object](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/-unit/). You use `Unit` as a return type in Kotlin when you would use `void` (lowercase v) in Java.

The `Nothing` type has no values. If a function has return type `Nothing`, then it cannot return normally. It either has to throw an exception, or enter an infinite loop. Code that follows a call to a function with return type `Nothing` will be marked as unreachable by the Kotlin compiler.

Because `Nothing` has no values, `Nothing?` is actually the type that captures only the `null` value in Kotlin.

Comment: Such a peculiar "data type". I thought programming is meant to be a sort of reflection of the real world. Can anyone point me to any literature, thread, forum that would explain the design logic behind the `Nothing` type?

Comment: @Mario In type theory, it is known as the "Bottom type". You can read some more about it here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bottom_type

Comment: @Mario `Nothing` is a useful type for a function that will never return. So, if a function always throws an exception or has a `while (true) {}` with no `break`s, it makes sense for the function's return type to be `Nothing`, since the compiler won't let you try to assign a `Nothing` to any other type, including `Unit`/`void`.

Comment: @Mario - `Nothing` is exactly what it sounds like. You have a function that never returns. What does it return? `Nothing`. Nobody will ever have it or have to deal with it. How about an empty list. What are the types of items within it? Again, `Nothing`. Thing of a singleton, except instead of one, there's none. Not even a single `Nothing` exists - only its class shows up, as it's never instantiated.

Answer (score 188):

## Unit

#### `Unit` is like `void`

In Kotlin, when a function does not return any meaningful value, it is declared to return `Unit`, just like `void` in Java:

```
fun greet(): Unit { println("Good day!") }
```

It's a convention to skip writing `Unit` when a function returns `Unit` because `Unit` is considered the default return type by the compiler:

```
fun greet() { println("Good day!") }
```

#### `Unit` is a Singleton

The `Unit` is a class with only a single object (singleton pattern) and that object is the `Unit` itself. It is declared in the `kotlin` package using an object declaration as shown below:

```
public object Unit {
    override fun toString() = "kotlin.Unit"
}
```

#### `Unit` in Functional Programming

Kotlin has first-class support for functional programming. It's common to have a `Unit` in a functional programming language. It makes the function types more readable by enabling all the functions to be declared as having a return value, even when a function does not return a value:

```
val greet: () -> Unit = { println("Good day!") }
```

Here, `() -> Unit` is a function type and the `Unit` after the `->` indicates that this function type does not return any meaningful value. Mentioning the `Unit` cannot be skipped in function types.

#### `Unit` for Extending Generics

Every function has to return a value.  Kotlin decided to represent this with a *class* rather than with a special type `void` as in Java. The reason for using a class is that the type system can be made more consistent by making it a part of the type hierarchy.

For example, let's say we have a generic `interface` called `Worker<T>` that performs some work. The `doWork()` function of this interface does some work and *has to return a value* `T`:

```
interface Worker<T> {
    fun doWork(): T
}
```

But sometimes, we might want to use this interface for some work *where we don't need to return any value*, for example, the work of logging, in the `LogWorker` class shown below that extends the `Worker` interface:

```
class LogWorker : Worker<Unit> {
    override fun doWork() {
        // Do the logging
    }
}
```

This is the magic of `Unit` where we are able to use the pre-existing interface that was originally designed to return a value. Here we make the `doWork()` function return the `Unit` value to serve our purpose in which we don't have anything to return. *So, it's useful when you override a function that returns a generic parameter.*

Notice that we have also skipped mentioning `Unit` return type for the `doWork()` function. There's no need to write a `return` statement either.

## Nothing

#### `Nothing`'s Value Never Exists

In Kotlin, the class `Nothing` represents *a value that never exists*. There can never be any value/object of this class because its `constructor` is kept `private`. It's defined in the `kotlin` package as follows:

```
public class Nothing private constructor()
```

`Nothing` is used for the return type of a function that never returns a value. For example, a function with an infinite loop or a function that always throws an exception. The `error()` function from Kotlin standard library is an example that always throws an exception and returns `Nothing`. Here is the code for it:

```
fun error(message: Any): Nothing = throw IllegalStateException(message.toString())
```

#### `Nothing` is the Bottom Type

In type theory, the type that has no values is called a bottom type and it is a subtype of all other types. So, `Nothing` is the *subtype* of all types in Kotlin, just like `Any?` is the *supertype* of all types. So, the value(that never exists) of type `Nothing` is assignable to the variables of all types, for example:

```
val user: User = request.user ?: error("User not found")
```

Here, we are calling the `error()` function that we defined earlier, if the `user` is `null`, using the elvis operator(`?:`). The `error()` function returns the value of type `Nothing` but it can be assigned to the variable of type `User` because `Nothing` is a subtype of `User`, just like it is a subtype of any other type. The compiler allows this because it knows that the `error()` function will never return a value, so there is no harm.

Similarly, you can return `Nothing` from a function that has any other return type:

```
fun getUser(request: Request): User {
    return request.user ?: error("User not found")
}
```

Here, even though the `getUser()` function is declared to return a `User`, it may return `Nothing`, if the `user` is `null`.

#### `Nothing` in Null Object Pattern

Consider the following example of a function that deletes the files given in a list:

```
fun deleteFiles(files: List<File>? = null) {
    if (files != null) files.forEach { it.delete() }
}
```

The problem with the design of this function is that it doesn't convey whether the `List<File>` is empty or `null` or has elements. Also, we need to check whether the list is `null` before using it.

To solve this problem, we use the null object design pattern. In null object pattern, instead of using a `null` reference to convey the absence of an object, we use an object which implements the expected interface, but leaves the method body empty.

So, we define the object of the interface `List<Nothing>`:

```
// This function is already defined in the Kotlin standard library
fun emptyList() = object : List<Nothing> {
    override fun iterator(): Iterator<Nothing> = EmptyIterator
    ...
}
```

Now we use this null object in our `deleteFiles()` function as a default value of our parameter:

```
fun deleteFiles(files: List<File> = emptyList()) {
    files.forEach { it.delete() }
}
```

This removes the uncertainty of `null` or empty and makes the intent clearer. It also removes the null checks because the functions on the null object are empty, they will be called but they are *no-ops* (no operation in them, so they will do nothing).

#### `Nothing` for Covariant Generics

In the example above, the compiler allows us to pass `List<Nothing>` where `List<File>` is expected. This is because the `List` interface in Kotlin is covariant since it's defined using the `out` keyword, that is, `List<out T>`. And as we learnt, `Nothing` is a subtype of all types, `Nothing` is a subtype of `File` too. And due to covariance, `List<Nothing>` is a subtype of `List<File>`, `List<Int>`, `List<User>` and so on... `List<AllTypes>`. This applies to any type with the covariant generics(`out`), not just `List`.

#### `Nothing` for Better Performance

Just like the function `emptyList()` used in our example, there are predefined functions like `emptyMap()`, `emptySet()`, `emptySequence()` that return null objects. All these are defined using `Nothing`. You can define your own objects like this.

The advantage here is that these return singleton objects, for example, you can call the same `emptyList()` function for getting an empty instance, whether it is for assigning to `List<File>`, `List<Int>` and ... `List<AllTypes>` and in multiple places. Since the same object is returned every time, it saves the cost of object creation and memory allocation.

## Void

#### `Void` for Extending Generics in Java

The `Void` class is from the `java.lang` package while the `Unit` and `Nothing` are from the `kotlin` package. `Void` is not intended to be used in Kotlin. Kotlin has its own class in the form of `Unit`.

`Void` is used in Java for extending generic interfaces like our `Worker` interface example written for `Unit` where we have to return a value. So for converting our Kotlin code to Java, we can use `Void` the same way we have used `Unit` for our `Worker` example and rewrite the code in Java as follows:

```
interface Worker<T> {
    T doWork();
}

class LogWorker implements Worker<Void> {
    @Override public Void doWork() {
        // Do the logging
        return null;
    }
}
```

Notice that when using `Void`, we have to use `Void` as a return type(can't skip) as well as need to write the `return` statement whereas for `Unit` we can skip both. This is another reason to avoid using `Void` in Kotlin code.

## Conclusion

So, `Unit` and `Nothing` are not a mistake by Kotlin designers in my opinion and are not as questionable as `null`, `undefined` and `void(0)` in Javascript. `Unit` and `Nothing` make the functional programming a breeze while providing other useful features mentioned. They are common in other functional programming languages too.

That's it!

Answer (score 15):

`Void` is uninstantiable type. It is a plain Java class and has no special meaning in Kotlin.

`Unit` type has only one value. Replaced Java `void` (notice: not `Void`). More info in [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html#unit-returning-functions).

`Nothing` has no instances (just like `Void`). It represents "a value that never exists". In Kotlin if you throw an error it is a `Nothing` (see [Kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/exceptions.html#the-nothing-type)).

Comment: And `Nothing?` is null :D

Comment: `Nothing` is like `never` in TypeScript