# Kotlin Result type with generics and Void/Nothing return type

Tags: android, generics, kotlin

I am trying to use Kotlin's `[Result][1]` type. Though in case of success it does not return any value. I cannot get it to work for returning the value. The following line gives me trouble: `complete(Result.success())`. It doest not compile. I tried with both `Result<Void>` and `Result<Nothing>` but cannot make it work.

Any suggestions about how to make it work?

```
package me.test.app

import android.util.Log

class Test {

    fun foo(complete: (Result<Nothing>) -> Unit) {
        if (Math.random() > 0.5) {
            complete(Result.success())
        } else {
            complete(Result.failure(Throwable("too low")))
        }
    }

    fun bar() {
        foo { result ->
            result.fold({
                Log.i("APP", "Success")
            })
            {
                Log.i("APP", "Failure")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You have to use `Result<Unit>`. Then you can call `complete` like this:

```
complete(Result.success(Unit))
```

Comment: An other option might be using `Nothing?` or `Void?` as type and completing it with `Result.success(null)`. Though thats up to preference and using Unit is cleaner imo

Comment: I'd stick with unit, too.
Nothing suggests that this function does not return at all (enter a loop, only throw)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/55953300/4451012